# query GitLab Container Registry programatically

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have access to a GitLab Container Registry and can push images as follows:

```
docker login --username $my_username -p $my_token $my_server/$my_project
docker tag $my_image:latest $my_server/$my_project/$my_image:latest
docker push $my_server/$my_project/$my_image:latest
```

I'd now like to use the [Container Registry API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html) as well and have tried this for a start (I'd like to list all tags subsequenty):

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $my_token" https://$my_server/api/v4/projects/$my_project/registry/repositories
```

However, this results in "404 page not found". What am I missing, shouldn't the URL be valid according to the documentation?

Comment: I don't use GitLab but I found this exact issue in a Google search. It was opened a couple years ago, but maybe it'll get you on the right track: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/56924

Comment: @MattU That same issue was also closed a couple of years ago and `https://$my_server/api/v4/projects/$my_project` also returns 404 in my case, so this is different.

Answer (score 0):

I have by now concluded that the most likely cause is that my access token `$my_token` has been granted only limited privileges by the GitLab admin.

This perhaps includes the scopes read_registry and write_registry, but not api.  Apparently there is no scope that specifically covers the Container Registry API without the rest of the GitLab API.